# Setting clientID for GIDSignIn in iOS app crashes

Tags: ios, gidsignin

I try to use GIDSignIn in my iOS app (ObjC). But when I do

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = GID_SIGN_IN_KEY;
```

in my app-delegate, I get and error `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

I'm using cocoapods to load the framework

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'GTMAppAuth'
pod 'AppAuth'
```

I configured the URL-scheme in my info.plist as described in the docs.

I'm building the app for iOS 14.

As suggested in countless posts on the web, I load `libz.tbd`, `SystemConfiguration.framework`, `StoreKit.framework`, `AddressBook.framework` and I set `-ObjC` in my other linker flags.

Alas, I'm still getting this error.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out the Google docs for the Youtube-API are outdated (again).

I had to use dependencies (github) instead of the pod-version of GIDSignIn. Then the signup-process worked.

Uploading a video was another pain in the a** since the docs use an outdated version of the GIDGoogleUser…

I will spare you my rant on Google now…